# VB.net Game Using Picture Boxes Functions

Tags: vb.net, function, image

I am trying to develop a simple game using picture boxes

For example, if you have 3 different picture boxes each containing a unique picture
When a form loads, one box is visible while other two are invisible
The player has to click on the visible picture box before it becomes invisible (time is specified for the box to stay visible)

Example: box 1 stays visible for 5 seconds , if the box is not clicked during the 5 seconds box 1 become invisible , and another random box will become visible.
Of course , if the user click on the picture successfully his score is updated
Different levels can be made by making the time shorter

The code would probably be one single code placed at the form load
Any help? Thanks

Comment: so what's the problem

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck? Please refer to [how to ask a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a stopwatch - a timer would be difficult because i dont know of a way to reset the count back to 0 when a user clicks sucessfully.

declare a stopwatch like so:

```
Private maxWaitTimer As New Stopwatch
```

then, perhaps a 'game loop' type of thing could be used in your form load event... maybe something like this:

```
maxWaitStopwatch.Start()

While(GameIsRunning)
    If maxWaitStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000 Then
        Losses = Losses + 1
        selectNewPictureBox()
        maxWaitStopwatch.Restart()
    Else
        Application.DoEvents() 'this gives the program a chance to execute the picture box click event, among other things (resize, drag, etc... since we are spinning in a loop)    
    End If
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) 'uncommenting this line will prevent it from maxing out your processor, although it will be slightly less responsive
End While
```

and your picture boxes could implement something like this:

```
Wins = Wins + 1
selectNewPictureBox()
maxWaitStopwatch.Restart()
```

basically, your program spins around in a loop, checking to see if the timer is elapsed, and if it is, it moves the picture.

the click event increments the score - it has a chance to be run during the 'application.doevents()' portion of the loop.

adding a sleep(100) will slow it down very slightly (and make it slightly more innaccurate, by about 100ms), but it will prevent it from using tons of CPU. you probably wont notice the difference in speed.

there may be better ways to do this, though...

---

EDIT - reflecting what steven said, it would be better if you used a timer instead of a loop:

use stop() when the user clicks the picture, and then call start() after.

(i didnt realize that would reset it, but apparently it does)

Comment: Sitting in an infinite loop calling `DoEvents` is really bad practice.  That kind of thing should be saved for last-resort situations.  A timer would be a much better solution.

Comment: looping is commonly used in games, though. how would the performance be better using a timer to fire the same code every 100ms, as opposed to looping, and sleeping for 100ms? ideally i would use a timer, and then reset the timer, but the timer in vb.net doesnt seem to have a function to reset the count to 0... or maybe it does, but i havent seen it

Comment: although you could probaby create a new timer every time, and destroy it once it gets to 5000ms / or if the user clicks the picture...

Comment: Calling `DoEvents` can be very dangerous.  It allows for unexpected behavior such as re-entrance into methods that may not be expecting it and may not be coded in such a way as to properly handle it.  It's not a matter of efficiency.  Besides that, when you sleep on the UI thread, it blocks the message loop (the winproc) from processing incoming windows messages.  If it's only for a 100 milliseconds, it may not be that noticeable, but even with a delay like that, you'll probably notice that dragging the form around the screen gets jumpy.

Comment: Lengthy loops are not a problem on other threads, or in non-winform projects.  In those cases, there's no reason to call `DoEvents` either since the loop isn't blocking the winproc message loop.  But, in WinForm projects, on the UI thread, you shouldn't be doing that kind of thing

Comment: I'm not sure which timer you are specifically talking about, but, just the basic WinForm timer that shows in the form designer tool box (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) allows you to reset the timer by calling `Stop` and then calling `Start` again (or by toggling the `Enabled` property).

Comment: i didnt realize that stop + start would reset it... i just figured it would pick up where it left off. good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer with an interval of 5000 and then in the elapsed event handler

```
Timer.stop()
Losses = Losses + 1
selectNewPictureBox()
Time.start()
```

Then in the picture box handler

```
Timer.stop()
Wins = Wins + 1
selectNewPictureBox()
Timer.start()
```

Comment: forgive me if this is a dumb question, but is it possible that a timer would fire twice? ...is it possible that the timer event can fire again before it reaches the Timer.stop() function? or is a timer blocked from firing until its previous iterations' event completes? (i realize that, even if possible, it would be extremely unlikely in this example, because 5 seconds is a super long time)

Comment: It should be unlikely, but possible if you have a lot of events. However the gui would start to lag significantly before that.